# How to loop over posts on homepage

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to loop over posts on a homepage with the following code:

```
$args = array ('taxonomy'=>'ad_cat', 'terms'=>'restaurants');

$category_posts = get_posts( $args );

if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
    $category_posts->the_post();
    the_content() ;     

endwhile;
else: 
  echo "Oops, there are no posts for category ". $cat->term_id .".<br/>";
endif;
```

but it returns no records (and those records exists).

My question is : how to loop properly over posts?

EDIT:

```
 ["taxonomy"]=>
    string(6) "ad_cat"
    ["terms"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(11) "restaurants"
    }
```

Comment: are you getting custom posts?

Comment: I want to get posts that belong to the 'Edited' query. But what I get is nothing (0 posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code :

```
$args = array(

        'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy'=>'ad_cat', 'terms'=>'restaurants'
            )
        )
    );

    $category_posts = get_posts( $args );

    if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
    while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
        $category_posts->the_post();
        the_content() ;     

    endwhile;
    else: 
      echo "Oops, there are no posts for category ". $cat->term_id .".<br/>";
    endif;
```